# Regarding rings and canonical embeddings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm currently (re)reading the paper *Homomorphic encryption for Arithmetic of Approximate Numbers* [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/421.pdf), and on page 8 there is this basic stuff I just can't work out.

Let $M=2^k$, $N=2^{k-1}$, $\mathcal{R}=\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^N+1)$ and $\sigma:\mathcal{R}\to\mathbb{C}^N$ be the canonical embedding such that $$\sigma(m)=(m(\zeta),m(\zeta^3),\ldots,m(\zeta^{2N-1}))$$
with $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/M)$.

From this we have that $\sigma(\mathcal{R})=\mathbb{H}=\{(z_j)\in\mathbb{C}^N:z_j=\overline{z_{N+1-j}}\}$, e.g. elements like $(2,3+i,5-i,5+i,3-i,2)$

Thus, they mention that $\mathbb{H}$ can be identified with $\mathbb{C}^{N/2}$ via the natural projection $\pi:\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{C}^{N/2}$ such that $\pi(z_j)=(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_{N/2})$ i.e. cutting them in half, e.g. $\pi(2,3+i,5-i,5+i,3-i,2)=(2,3+i,5-i)$. So far so good.

Up to this point this suggests that $\pi^{-1}(\mathbb{C}^{N/2})=\mathbb{H}$ but then, they mention that there might be some $w\in\mathbb{C}^{N/2}$ such that $\pi^{-1}(w)$ is not contained in $\mathbb{H}$ and I just can't make sense of this.

Thanks

Comment: This looks contradictory indeed. Not sure what they are trying to say.